# how do I fill the gaps between pixel in bmp file after loading the pixel array into the array with padded rows

Tags: c++, arrays, c, bmp

I wrote a program in c++ to draw the pixel of bmp image into the console using SetPixel windows function, but after loading the pixel array into the array the image got printed on the console with gaps between the pixels. Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

This is the output of the printed image on the console.

This is the original Image I provided to it.

[image]

As you can see here the image width also changes after the print on the console.

```
// bmp bitmap
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma pack(1)
struct BitmapFileHeader {
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned short reserved1;
    unsigned short reserved2;
    unsigned int offset;
};
#pragma pack(0)

unsigned char grayScale(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b) {
    return ((r + g + b) / 3);
}
int main() {
    char *data;
    FILE *filePointer;
    int **ImageArray;
    BitmapFileHeader *bmp = (struct BitmapFileHeader*)malloc(sizeof(struct BitmapFileHeader));
    BITMAPINFOHEADER *BitmapInfoHeader = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC context = ::GetDC(console) ;
    
    filePointer = fopen("tom.bmp", "rb");
    if(!filePointer) {
        perror("");
    }
    fread(reinterpret_cast<BitmapFileHeader*>(bmp), sizeof(BitmapFileHeader), 1, filePointer);
    fread(reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFOHEADER*>(BitmapInfoHeader), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, filePointer);

    if(BitmapInfoHeader->biSize == 40 && BitmapInfoHeader->biCompression == BI_BITFIELDS) {
        printf("This types of image uses Extra bit masks\n");
    }
    // row pading 
    int RowSize = ((BitmapInfoHeader->biBitCount * BitmapInfoHeader->biWidth + 31) / 32) * 4;
    int PixelArraySize = RowSize * BitmapInfoHeader->biHeight;
    int height = BitmapInfoHeader->biHeight * 5;
    int width = BitmapInfoHeader->biWidth * 5;
    
    printf("RowSize: %d PixelArraySize: %d\n", RowSize, PixelArraySize);
    
    ImageArray = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*height);
    
    // memory allocation
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        ImageArray[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*width);
        
    data = (char*)malloc(PixelArraySize);
    fseek(filePointer, bmp->offset, SEEK_SET);
    
     
    // set image into array 
    for(int ii = 0; ii < height; ii+=3) {
        fread(data, RowSize, 3, filePointer);
        for(int jj = 0; jj < width; jj+=3) {
            ImageArray[ii][jj] = grayScale(data[jj+2], data[jj+1], data[jj]);
                SetPixel(context, -jj+1000, -ii+500, RGB(data[jj+2], data[jj+1], data[jj]));
            }
    }
    fclose(filePointer);
    return 0;
}
```

here is the code, which I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pixel is described by three bytes, one for each RGB channel. You are dealing with two indices here: The index of the pixel in the row data and the position of the pixel in width direction. You place the pixel and access the row data with the same index.

So:

```
    for (int jj = 0; jj < width; jj++) {      // jj: position
        int kk = 3 * jj;                      // kk: data index

        ImageArray[ii][jj] = grayScale(data[kk + 2], data[kk + 1], data[kk]);
        SetPixel(context, -jj + 1000, -ii + 500, RGB(data[kk + 2], data[kk + 1], data[kk]));
    }
```

The vertical gaps, i.e. the blank lines, come from incrementing by 3, where you should just increment by 1. (You have no "data index" here, because you read your data row-wide for the current row `ii`.)

If you want to enlarge your image, as the multiplication of width and height by 5 suggests, you must add a third index: You now have two positions, the source and target positions. This will be easier if you separate your loops: Create `ImageArray` of the source image in a first nested loop, then draw your scaled target image to the console with a loop over the target oordinates:

```
int scale = 5;
int ww = scale * w;
int hh = scale * h;

// read ImageArray

for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    fread(data, RowSize, 3, filePointer);

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        ImageArray[y][x] = ...;
            SetPixel(context, -jj+1000, -ii+500, RGB(data[jj+2], data[jj+1], data[jj]));
        }
}

for (int yy = 0; yy < hh; yy++) {
    fread(data, RowSize, 3, filePointer);

    for (int xx = 0; xx < ww; xx++) {
        int x = xx / scale;
        int y = yy / scale;

        SetPixel(context, yy, xx, ImageArray[y][x]);
    }
}
```

(Here, single letters re source values, double leters are target values.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay, I have changed the increment by one and the rbg is change to gray, and still the gaps are there but minimized, the reason I multiplied the width and height is to enlarge the array, if I don't multiply it by 5 the image will be displayed in half.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you must then use `data[3 * jj + 2]` and so on. Alternatively, you can leave the increment of 3 and say `SetPixel(context, -jj / 3 + 1000, ...)`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wow it worked thanks brother but what does `-jj / 3` mean?

Comment: Sir, update your answer and let me accept it as answered

Comment: another thing what if I want to upscale it by 5 or with some factor?